# Get Current Phone Location without GPS and Internet

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am checking for some functionality for Windows Phone 8.

As per my knowledge there is two way to find current location. 
1. GPS
2. GSM

Wnidows Phone 8 as Geolocator class that help us to find GPS based location. Does there is any API to get location without GPS and internet?

Comment: But how without both GPS and GSM?

Comment: I want to is that possible without GPS ? How to get GSM based location ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GeoLocator APIs internally check GPS, GSM (using cell tower triangulation) and WiFi to determine the current position based on the specified accuracy. If  you don't want to use GPS or GSM triangulation, the only way to find the position is to connect to Wi-Fi (with internet access).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way without GPS or Internet.    You have GPS, GSM, and WiFi for your GeoLocator API.    If the phone does not have any of those techs enabled/available to you - there's no way for you to determine the location of the phone.   With Windows 8.1, you also have IP address (but that's a terrible choice).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.positionsource.aspx